# how to list files and directory in a path without recursive under clojure

Tags: java, file, clojure

[image]

this method can't satisfy entirely me because that it's recursive.
I just need to list files and directory of current path.

like this...
the example can't print it as follows.

> [image]

thanks!

Comment: In the future, try to copy and past text into code blocks (use `Ctrl + K` to indent the code block). This makes it more easily searchable in Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use .list to get the directory listing for a given path like so.

```
user=> (require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
nil
user=> (map pprint (.list (io/file "./")))
".android"
".AndroidStudio2.0"
".ansible"
".anyconnect"
```